# Regex for replacing a particular occurrence of a String in Javascript

Tags: javascript

For some weird reason, I can't seem to figure out how to solve my current issue.

I have a string that contains this string `/partners:` and I wish to remove all occurrences of `/partners:` from the string

I have tried the below code

```
retrievedData = retrievedData
            .replace("/\/partners:", "")
```

But for some weird reason it is not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use either `replaceAll` or a regex literal instead

Comment: that's not regex

Comment: I think you want `replace(/\/partners:/g, "")`

Comment: When you pass a string to `replace`, it looks for **exactly** that string. Your string has two `/` in it at the beginning (one of them pointlessly escaped), so naturally it doesn't match a string with just one `/` at the beginning. To match `/partners:`, use `.replace("/partners:", "")`. If you need to use a regular expression, though, then in the regular expression literal you'd have to escape the `/`: `.replace(/\/partners:/, "")`. But there's no indication you need a regular expression here.